# The figurative expression "fare un fischio a qualcuno"

Tags: meaning

> Se hai bisogno di qualcosa, **mi fai un fischio**.

This expression literally means "give me a whistle", but I wonder if its figurative meaning extends to "give me **a holler / a shout**" or "give me **a call** (on the phone)"?

Comment: Alone-zee, with a question like this, you are basically asking someone else to look up _fischio_ in a monolingual dictionary rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: I agree with @DaG: I would recommend trying to use some monoligual dictionaries before asking this kind of questions. If then you don't understand them or some doubts remain, write a question that includes your research and an explanation of what it's not clear to you (for instance, in this case, the fact if this expression can refer to a telephone call).

Comment: Actually, it goes deeper than that, as the dictionaries I consult do not mention anything about a telephone call, for instance, which I'm asking about here. Not to mention the fact that not everyone on this site is fluent enough in Italian to be able to fully appreciate what is written in  monolingual dictionaries. I only ask a question about something that I couldn't work out on my own after consulting several websites and dictionaries, so I as a learner would be at a loss if these questions were regarded as "inadequate". These kinds of questions are frequently asked on other SE sites.

Comment: @Alone-zee: I'm afraid I didn't express myself very well. I didn't mean that this kind of questions is inappropriate, I was only trying to refer to the way of writing good questions. Even if you are not fluent in Italian, I think it's a good idea to have a look to some monoligual dictionaries and, if this doesn't help because you don't understand them, mention that in the question.

Comment: @Alone-zee: And, in this specific case, I believe the question would improve if you include in its body what you said in your comment: "I had a look at some websites and dictionaries, but none of them mention anything about a telephone call ...". In my opinion, in this way it would be clearer what you are asking.

Comment: @Alone-zee: And let me ask you this: are you OK with the answers written in Italian? Or would you prefer answers in English? I believe that the kind of questions you are asking gives the impression you are fluent enough to understand answers in Italian, but maybe it's not the case.

Comment: @Alone-zee: I would like to add that what I said is a personal opinion (based on my own experience as a language learner) which is not necessarily shared by this site community.

Comment: @Charo Grammar-wise, it does not pose much of a problem. But given my rather limited vocabulary at the moment, I need to consult a dictionary a lot to read through an answer written in Italian. So that would be "yes and no". At least for now, I feel more comfortable with answers in English. I've only  been learning Italian for about 45 days in total, after all.

Answer (score 6):

Sì, questa espressione viene usata comunemente per indicare genericamente e indifferentemente tutti i modi di contattare qualcuno (incluso via telefono).

Come dice il De Mauro, l'espressione puo essere intesa sia in senso letterale che figurativo. Direi che viene più comunemente usata in senso figurato.

***[Fare un fischio](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fare-un-fischio):***

> fischiare per richiamare l’attenzione di qcn. | ***con riferimento al valore simbolico del gesto***, avvertire, avvisare: *quando hai finito fai un fischio*.

---

Yes, this expression is often used to indicate generically and indifferently all the ways of contacting someone (telephone included).

As described in the De Mauro dictionary, the expression can be understood both literally and figuratively. I'd say the figurative usage is more common.

***[Fare un fischio](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fare-un-fischio):***

> to whistle to attract the attention of someone. | ***with reference to the symbolic value of the act***, warn, give notice: *quando hai finito fai un fischio*.

Comment: E, come ha chiesto l'OP, pensi che, se uno fosse al telefono e dicesse "se hai bisogno di qualcosa, fammi un fischio" intenderebbe una chiamata telefonica?

Comment: @Charo - fare un fischio è un modo molto informale per dire “far sapere, avvertire”.  Che poi uno  lo faccia usando il telefono o qualsiasi altro mezzo di comunicazioni non fa differenza

Comment: Since the OP has explicitly said that [he/she feels more comfortable with answers in English](https://italian.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/20936), may someone **add** (I think there is no need to delete this Italian version) a translation or a similar explanation in English?

Comment: Many thanks for the translation, @DenisNardin!!